# Spring execute method after hibernate lazy loading

Tags: spring, hibernate, lazy-loading, spring-data-jpa, spring-aop

I am using Spring Boot 1.3.1 including Spring Data JPA. I'd like to execute a method after any lazy loading to do some translations on the loaded object.

Example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "commune")
public class Commune extends CommuneBase {
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class CommuneBase {
    private Region region;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "region")
public class Region extends RegionBase {
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class RegionBase {
    private String name;
}
```

Testcode:

```
Commune commune = communeRepository.findOne(communeId);
Region region = commune.getRegion();
```

The result of `getRegion()` should now be translated.
I tried it with an aspect and the following pointcut:

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut="execution(* com.mycompany.application.data.domain.Commune.getRegion(..))", returning="returnValue")
```

The pointcut is not called. Other pointcuts in the same project are working as expected.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Spring will only apply AOP to beans it knows and controllers. You are trying to use Spring AOP on entities and that isn't going work.

Comment: Sometimes... Thank you for the hint! Any ideas how to solve that problem without AOP?

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve that you think you need to use AOP to solve it.

Comment: My application is multilingual and i'd like to get the correct translation of `region.name` any time i get an instance of a region depending on the logged in user. So for direct loading via the `regionRepository` i achived it by a pointcut. So i tried it for lazy loaded instances too.
I do not want to call a `translate(Region region)` any time in the code

Comment: IMHO you are approaching it wrong. Spring has I18N support and you should integrate with that, instead of trying to slap on a solution with AOP.

Comment: I'll give the I18N a try. Thanks for your fast help. If you want some credit, give an answer and i will it mark as solved.